# Ubuntu hard disk space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a ~1 TB hard disk that I have partitioned for dual booting Ubuntu and Windows, where Ubuntu is the primary OS being used. Recently, I have been running into disk space issues in Ubuntu, and have approximately 200GB that is unaccounted for.

Below you can see the outputs of:

```
# sudo fdisk -l
/dev/nvme0***          *****     *****    *****   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0***          *****     *****    *****    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0<microsoft>  *****     *****    ***** 464.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0***          *****     *****    *****   500M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0<linux>      *****     *****    ***** 466.5G Linux filesystem

# sudo df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            3.2G  2.4M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0<linux>459G  314G  122G  73% /
tmpfs            16G  214M   16G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0****   256M   33M  224M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs            3.2G  124K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000

# sudo du ./ -h --threshold 500M | sort -h
./ 108 GB
```

When running `sudo du`, I can see that all 300 GB is occupied, but it is not located in the home directory. How do I locate and delete these 200 GB?

edit:

Output of disk analyzer (baobab)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You seem to have one filesystem only, so `/home` is part of the root file system `/`. What was the current directory when you ran the `du` command? If you ran it in your home directory, run it in the root directory `sudo du / ...` You could also use the graphical disk usage analyzer `baobab`.

Comment: This helped!!! 

`sudo du / -h --threshold 500M | sort -h`
gave me

220G /var/lib/docker/overlay2
221G /var/lib/docker
224G /var/lib


So it is easy to see that docker is what is taking up all the space...

Comment: Ran the following command afterward:

`docker system prune -a -f` to remove all docker related info. Note this will delete all your docker images etc. so be careful.

Comment: Your comments look like an answer. You can answer your own question.

Comment: I know, just wanted you to get the credit for it

Comment: By the way, please don't hide essential information from the output. The name of your disk isn't sensitive information, there's no point in `nvme0*** ` and actually the real values can be informative since they let us know whether two `dev/nme0**` devices are the same or not. The same goes for the start and end positions of your partitions, the is no risk in sharing that and it might be useful.

Comment: I didn't write an answer because your question is not clear enough. You did not provide all information I requested in my first comment. I don't know if the `./` in your `du` command  was intentional or a typo or a misunderstanding. `du ./` is the same as `du .` or `du` without a directory argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments by @bodo i figured out that the issue was that the 200gbs were taken up in a folder in `/` (files generated by docker). By running

`sudo du / -h --threshold 500M | sort -h`

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2 221G 
/var/lib/docker 224G
```

I could identify what was taking up the space and then i ran

`docker system prune -a -f`

to remove all docker related info. Note this will delete all your docker images etc. so be careful.